# set value in the datagridview textbox

Tags: c#, datagridview, textbox

how to set the value of datagridview textbox i.e each row with textbox should contain some value (e.g in my case 0.0) and also if user doesn't enter any value it should set value 0.0.

I tried to use cellleave event of datagridview but its not helping...

what i am really want to do is set the certain default value in cell if user does not give any input. Once user lefts the current cell it should show the default value.

now this is my code

```
private void dgvSellbox_CellLeave(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            if (dgvSellbox.CurrentCell.Value == null )
            {
                dgvSellbox.CurrentCell.Value = 0.0;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Can you paste the code you're using for that purpose? Also try adding some more details on the context of your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set defaults for the a column by the designer

> 1. On you DataGridView -> Click Edit Columns
> 2. Now you should see the Edit Columsn Dialog
> 3. Select the Column you want to set default
> 4. Now at the right side you should the property called DataGridViewCellStyle
> 5. Please click on DataGridViewCellStyle this will show Cell Style Builder Dialog
> 6. Under Data -> Set the NullValue property to 0.0
> 7. Keep on clicking Ok Buttons till you are back to the DataGridView

Hope this helps...